# Typescript - function return type as interface

Tags: typescript

I'm looking at possibility to define return type of a function as type, that implements interface

not instance of a type, that implements interface, the type itself

with types I can do:

```
interface A {
  doSomething(): number;
}

class Base implements A {
  doSomething() { return 1; }
}

class Ext1 extends Base {
  doSomething() { return 2; }
}

class Ext2 extends Base {
  doSomething() { return 3; }
}


function process(x: number): typeof Base | null {
  if (x === 1) {
    return Ext1;
  } else if (x === 2) {
    return Ext2;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Which is your normal factory function based on condition

The problem is, I do have to define `Base` class I do not care about at all and do some dummy implementations of `A`

What I'm looking for is:

```
interface A {
  doSomething(): number;
}


class Ext1 implements A {
  doSomething() { return 2; }
}

class Ext2 implements A {
  doSomething() { return 3; }
}


function process(x: number): typeof A | null {
  if (x === 1) {
    return Ext1;
  } else if (x === 2) {
    return Ext2;
  }
  return null;
}
```

but error happens
`'A' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)`

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need a constructor signature:

```
function process(x: number): (new () => A) | null { 
    // ...
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnICYD2AygQLYRgAWoA5gBQCUAXMiAK6kBG0A3FgL5YhCADZwAzuOQBRAB5gAjMmCkADiIjlwU9NlyES5KrUaZkUCmyghkAJh7JBgrKIlS5YW8rUatYHZg4+MRkFNQg9AxmFmBWNgDMDk5CWDBsIAhgwAQ2qlAESJJ0sizsXNDMyHQgEADuVVEAvAB8aFEAPqxsIiJmQcAwVbLIjaPIClF6uOaW1jLyCny4-MgQIuIoA0MjY7aTQbgxcfOeS45BR3PsPXz8QA)